# Bug in Mathematica TeXForm generating \left\left

Tags: bugs, latex

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and persisting through 11.3 or later**

---

I asked about this in the TeX chat. It seems Mathematica generate invalid Latex in this example.

```
ClearAll[y,x];
ode = D[y[x], x] - (y[x]^2 + 1)/(Abs[y[x] + (1 + y[x])^(1/2)]*(1 + x)^(3/2));
TeXForm[ode]
```

The output is

```
y'(x)-\frac{y(x)^2+1}{(x+1)^{3/2} \left\left| y(x)+\sqrt{y(x)+1}\right\right| }
```

Using `\left\left` is illegal. TeXLive 2014 will not compile it. MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}

y'(x)-\frac{y(x)^2+1}{(x+1)^{3/2} \left\left| y(x)+\sqrt{y(x)+1}\right\right| }

\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Compile:

```
 pdflatex foo.tex

! Missing delimiter (. inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \left 
l.7 ...eft\left| y(x)+\sqrt{y(x)+1}\right\right| }

?
```

Just wanted to confirm with others if this is a bug before send email to supprt@wolfram.com unless someone finds a smart fix or an option to solve this.

V9.01 and V10.

**Update:**

If any one gets such a case, the fix in this example is to simply remove the extra `\left` at the outers. Like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
y'(x)-\frac{y(x)^2+1}{(x+1)^{3/2} \left| y(x)+\sqrt{y(x)+1}\right| }
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Compiles now ok. The output is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

fyi, just send an email to support@wolfram.com as well. Experts in Latex at TeX forum confirmed the code generated by Mathematica is wrong.

Comment: The same here using `9.0.1.0` on Linux.

Comment: The problematic part seems to be that inside `Abs` is an expression which possibly requires scaled boundaries, because the expression is too large. Therefore, this works `TeXForm[Abs[x + 1]]` while this `TeXForm[Abs[x + 1/2]]` is introducing the extra `left`/`right` pair. Can find more notation like `Abs` and `Norm` that surround an expression?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## Why we're getting this buggy result

In process of conversion to $\TeX$, whenever *Mathematica* encounters "something delimited" i.e. `RowBox` with something surrounded with `String`s matching:

```
"(" | "[" | "\[LeftModified]" | "\[LeftDoubleBracket]" | "{" | "\[Piecewise]" | "\[LeftFloor]" | "\[LeftCeiling]" | "\[LeftAngleBracket]" | "\[LeftSkeleton]" | "«" | "\[LeftBracketingBar]" | "\[LeftDoubleBracketingBar]" | ")" | "]" | "\[RightModified]" | "\[RightDoubleBracket]" | "}" | "\[RightFloor]" | "\[RightCeiling]" | "\[RightAngleBracket]" | "\[RightSkeleton]" | "»" | "\[RightBracketingBar]" | "\[RightDoubleBracketingBar]" | "/" | "\\" | "|" | "\[VerticalSeparator]" | "||"`
```

then it tests, whether those delimited boxes can potentially result in something higher then line height, using `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`DelimiterBoxQ `` function.

If `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`DelimiterBoxQ `` returns `False`, then "ordinary translation" to $\TeX$ occurs and delimiters are converted using `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex `` function, which for `Abs` `TraditionalForm` delimiters: `"\[LeftBracketingBar]"`, `"\[RightBracketingBar]"` returns `"\\left| "` and `"\\right| "` respectively.

That's why we get:

```
Abs[x + 1]//TeXForm
(* \\left| x+1\\right| *)
```

If `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`DelimiterBoxQ `` returns, `True` then delimiters are converted using `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`InsertDelimiters `` function which adds `\\left` or `\\right` to result of conversion of delimiter with `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$TeXDelimiterReplacements `` rules.

`` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$TeXDelimiterReplacements `` contains replacement rules for delimiters like `"\[LeftAngleBracket]" -> {"\\langle "}`. Among them, for unknown reason, two pairs of $\TeX$ delimiters contain additional `"\\left"` and `"\\right"` commands:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$TeXDelimiterReplacements // TableForm
(*
    ...
    \[LeftBracketingBar] -> {\left| }
    \[LeftDoubleBracketingBar] -> {\left\| }
    ...
    \[RightBracketingBar] -> {\right| }
    \[RightDoubleBracketingBar] -> {\right\| }
    ...
*)
```

In case of `"\[LeftBracketingBar]"`, `"\[LeftDoubleBracketingBar]"` and their right counterparts, `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`InsertDelimiters `` function adds additional `\\left` and `\\right` to delimiters that already have them from `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$TeXDelimiterReplacements `` rules.

That's why we get:

```
Abs[x + 1/2]//TeXForm
(* \left\left| x+\frac{1}{2}\right\right| *)
```

This bug was introduced in *Mathematica* version 9. In version 8 there are no additional `\\left` and `\\right` commands neither in `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$TeXDelimiterReplacements `` rules, nor in `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`maketex `` function.

---

## How to fix this bug

Fixing this bug is easy, we just need to patch `` System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$TeXDelimiterReplacements `` rules:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$TeXDelimiterReplacements =
    System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$TeXDelimiterReplacements /. {
        "\\left| " | "\\right| " -> "|",
        "\\left\\| " | "\\right\\| " -> "\\| "
    }
```

Now we get correct $\TeX$ code:

```
Abs[x] // TeXForm
(* \left| x\right| *)

Abs[x + 1/2] // TeXForm
(* \left|x+\frac{1}{2}\right| *)

D[y[x], x] - (y[x]^2 + 1)/(Abs[y[x] + (1 + y[x])^(1/2)]*(1 + x)^(3/2)) // TeXForm
(* y'(x)-\frac{y(x)^2+1}{(x+1)^{3/2} \left|y(x)+\sqrt{y(x)+1}\right|} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed in 12.1.1:

```
$Version

(* 12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 9, 2020) *)

ClearAll[y, x];
ode = D[y[x], x] - (y[x]^2 + 1)/(Abs[y[x] + (1 + y[x])^(1/2)]*(1 + x)^(3/2));
TeXForm[ode]

(* y'(x)-\frac{y(x)^2+1}{(x+1)^{3/2} \left|y(x)+\sqrt{y(x)+1}\right| } *)
```