# How can I convert from a set of lists to equations in the form LaTeX?

Tags: output-formatting, latex

I have a set

```
  {{1, -9, 17, 2, -12, 19}, {1, -1, -3, 2, -8, 9}, {1, 1, -8, 3, -13, 
  16}, {2, -4, -1, 3, -11, 11}, {3, -7, 1, 4, -14, 13}, {3, -5, -4, 
  5, -19, 20}, {4, -10, 3, 5, -17, 15}, {5, -13, 5, 6, -20, 17}}
```

I want to convert each list to an equation in the form

$$\left |ax^2 + bx + c \right | = dx^2 + ex + f.$$
For example, with $\{5, -13, 5, 6, -20, 17\}$, I write to 
$$\left |5x^2 - 13x + 5 \right | = 6x^2 -20x + 17.$$
I tried

```
v = {5, -13, 5, 6, -20, 17};
u = {x^2, x , 1};
Abs[{v[[1]]
    , v[[2]]
    , v[[3]]
    }. {x^2, x , 1}] == {v[[4]]
   , v[[5]]
   , v[[6]]}.{x^2, x , 1}
```

I got

> Abs[5 - 13 x + 5 x^2] == 17 - 20 x + 6 x^2

If I used `TeXForm`

```
v = {5, -13, 5, 6, -20, 17};
u = {x^2, x , 1};
Abs[{v[[1]]
     , v[[2]]
     , v[[3]]
     }. {x^2, x , 1}] == {v[[4]]
    , v[[5]]
    , v[[6]]}.{x^2, x , 1} // TeXForm
```

I got

> \left\left| 5 x^2-13 x+5\right\right| =6 x^2-20x+17

When I copy this line into *TexMaker*, it can not comppile.

My two questions are:

1) How can I get `\left| 5 x^2-13 x+5\right| = 6 x^2-20x+17` when I use

```
v = {5, -13, 5, 6, -20, 17};
u = {x^2, x , 1};
Abs[{v[[1]]
     , v[[2]]
     , v[[3]]
     }. {x^2, x , 1}] == {v[[4]]
    , v[[5]]
    , v[[6]]}.{x^2, x , 1} // TeXForm
```

2) How can I convert all list in the set?

```
{{1, -9, 17, 2, -12, 19}, {1, -1, -3, 2, -8, 9}, {1, 1, -8, 3, -13, 
      16}, {2, -4, -1, 3, -11, 11}, {3, -7, 1, 4, -14, 13}, {3, -5, -4, 
      5, -19, 20}, {4, -10, 3, 5, -17, 15}, {5, -13, 5, 6, -20, 17}}
```

Comment: It appears to be a bug in TeXForm.

Comment: This is known bug. [possible-bug-in-mathematica-texform-generating-left-left](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54857/possible-bug-in-mathematica-texform-generating-left-left) proposed fix also posted. WRI should really fix this. This was reported 2 years ago.

Comment: @Nasser You're right - I had even upvoted your question and the answer back then, but forgot... I guess this means the question can be closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bug in TeXForm. It shows up when there are exponents in the argument for `Abs[]`, suggesting that it adds `\left` and `\right` when it thinks it needs to to make the absolute value bars bigger for the exponent, not realizing that `Abs[]` already generated `\left|` and `\right|`.

This applies the equation generation, the TeXForm, and a workaround for the bug to all of the list items:

```
StringReplace[ToString[TeXForm[Abs[#1 x^2+#2 x+#3]==#4 x^2+#5 x+#6]],
    {"\\left\\left"->"\\left","\\right\\right"->"\\right"}]&@@@
{{1,-9,17,2,-12,19},{1,-1,-3,2,-8,9},{1,1,-8,3,-13,16},{2,-4,-1,3,-11,11},
{3,-7,1,4,-14,13},{3,-5,-4,5,-19,20},{4,-10,3,5,-17,15},{5,-13,5,6,-20,17}}
```

> ```
> {\left| x^2-9 x+17\right| =2 x^2-12 x+19,
>  \left| x^2-x-3\right| =2 x^2-8 x+9,
>  \left| x^2+x-8\right| =3 x^2-13 x+16,
>  \left| 2 x^2-4 x-1\right| =3 x^2-11 x+11,
>  \left| 3 x^2-7 x+1\right| =4 x^2-14 x+13,
>  \left| 3 x^2-5 x-4\right| =5 x^2-19 x+20,
>  \left| 4 x^2-10 x+3\right| =5 x^2-17 x+15,
>  \left| 5 x^2-13 x+5\right| =6 x^2-20 x+17}
> ```

$$\left| x^2-9 x+17\right| =2 x^2-12 x+19$$
$$\left| x^2-x-3\right| =2 x^2-8 x+9$$
$$\left| x^2+x-8\right| =3 x^2-13 x+16$$
$$\left| 2 x^2-4 x-1\right| =3 x^2-11 x+11$$
$$\left| 3 x^2-7 x+1\right| =4 x^2-14 x+13$$
$$\left| 3 x^2-5 x-4\right| =5 x^2-19 x+20$$
$$\left| 4 x^2-10 x+3\right| =5 x^2-17 x+15$$
$$\left| 5 x^2-13 x+5\right| =6 x^2-20 x+17$$

Comment: How Can I add symbol  ` \ \ ` inorder break line of each equation?

Comment: `StringRiffle[{"s1","s2","s3"},"\\\\"]` gives `s1\\s2\\s3`.

Comment: But I got `StringRiffle[{"s1", "s2", "s3"}, "\\\\"]`

Comment: @minthao_2011 For versions before 10.1, use `StringJoin@Riffle[...]` for `StringRiffle[...]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank for your help. I use version 10.02.

Comment: If I have 10000 lines, StringJoin@Riffle[{"s1", "s2", "s3", "s10000"], how can I add symbol '' '' ?

Comment: @MarkAdler Please help me add ` \ \ ` in your code apter each equation. I have a bout 10000 equations.

Comment: You already have that help in the comments above.

Answer (score 3):

The following also works. It doesn't require any string replacements in the output. All I did is to re-define the set of variables `u` such that it contains the second power of `x` as a `String`:

```
v={5,-13,5,6,-20,17};
u={"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)",x,1};
Abs[{v[[1]],v[[2]],v[[3]]}.u]=={v[[4]],v[[5]],v[[6]]}.u//TeXForm
```

> `\left| 5 x^2-13 x+5\right| =6 x^2-20 x+17`

The strange-looking string `"\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(x\), \(2\)]\)"` above is actually entered by typing $"\!x^2\!"$ as a string. So really, I have $u = \{"\!x^2\!",x,1\}$. What you see in the copyable code above is the ugly `InputForm` representation of this formatted string.

This is based on the observation by @Mark Adler that the bug occurs when there is a two-dimensional object inside the bracketing bar that may require a height adjustment. What happens in that case is that *Mathematica* `TraditionalForm` outputs a `TemplateBox` with tag `Abs`, instead of a literal `RowBox` containing the bracketing bars explicitly. So the `TemplateBox` is apparently where the bug occurs when going from `TraditionalForm` to `TeXForm` (that is the route by which `TeXForm` is generated).

Comment: I down't understand, I got `\left| -13 x+5
   \text{x${}^{\wedge}$2}+5\right| =-20
   x+6 \text{x${}^{\wedge}$2}+17`

Comment: Oh yes, I see this was copied incorrectly from my notebook to the answer. The string should be entered as a real superscript, $"x^2"$...

Comment: That's right. Thank you.