# Problem with TeXForm

Tags: latex

I have expression:

```
Abs[Hypergeometric1F1[-n, m + 1, x]]^2 // TeXForm
```

Give  me error during editing this question **(Missing or unrecognized delimiter for \left)** if i put here:

$\left\left| \, _1F_1(-n;m+1;x)\right\right| {}^2$

If I convert back:

```
ToExpression["$\left\left| \, _1F_1(-n;m+1;x)\right\right| {}^2$", \TeXForm]
```

MMA  again give me error:**(Error:  expected)**

What could be the reason?.Thank you.

```
$Version
(*  "11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)
```

Comment: Works fine for me (MMA 10.4.0.0, Mac OS 10.10.3).

Comment: The same errors on MMA `10.2`!

Comment: Related: [possible bug in Mathematica TeXForm? Generating \left\left](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54857/14303).

Comment: @jkuczm. Thanks its works. :)